# How do you print a struct in LLDB that can be used in C code

Tags: c, lldb

I would like to print a struct and then be able to copy/ paste the output into some of my code for setting up unit tests.

ie something like

```
typedef struct FOO{
   int array[5];
   const char * string;
   char stringBuff[5];
} FOO;

FOO a = {.array = {1,2,3,4,5},
    .string = "TEST",
    .stringBuff = {"test"}
};
```

then in LLDB get something like

```
print a
    FOO a = {.array = {1,2,3,4,5},
    .string = "TEST",
    .stringBuff = {"test"}
};
```

Comment: Did you already see this: [Type Summary](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/variable.html#type-summary)?

Comment: I did, not sure how to change the format so that 
A. Each field gets a comma after it.
B. Arrays drop the indexes.
C. Structures, and arrays use {} around their initalizer.
D. field names get period in front of them.

Comment: You can implement a type summary in Python, at which point you can get all the values from all the struct children and format them however you want.

Comment: I wouldn't do it as a summary at that point, however, since summaries are suppose to be on one line, etc...  I'd make a python command "format_variable" or something like that, and do the job there.